# Numpy - Multiple Outer Products

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there's a way to compute multiple outer products and stack the results in a single operation.

Say I have an Nx1 vector and take the outer product with a 1xM vector, the result will be an NxM matrix.

What if I had an NxR matrix A, and an RxM matrix B. Is it possible to construct an NxMxR matrix where each layer of the output matrix is the outer product of the corresponding column of A and row of B?

I know it's really easy to do this in a single for loop over R, but I wanted to know if there's a faster way using numpy builtins (as there usually is when numpy is concerned).

I haven't been able to figure out a set of indices that work with einsum (and I'm not even sure if einsum is the right approach, since there is no summation involved here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) or Einsum (the fact that there is no summation does not matter)

```
N, M, R = 8, 9, 16

A = numpy.random.rand(N)
B = numpy.random.rand(M)

C = A[:, None] * B[None, :]
D = numpy.einsum('a,b->ab', A, B)
numpy.allclose(C, D)
# True
C.shape
# (8, 9)

A = numpy.random.rand(N, R)
B = numpy.random.rand(M, R)

C = A[:, None, :] * B[None, :, :]
D = numpy.einsum('ar,br->abr', A, B)
numpy.allclose(C, D)
# True
C.shape
# (8, 9, 16)
```

Comment: can you explain how the broadcasting works? Is it essentially reshaping the array to add an empty axis?

Comment: Yup, that's what's happening. I have added a link to the NumPy docs about broadcasting.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I didn't make the connection with how an element-wise multiplication broadcast like that was equivalent to the outer product. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nils, I am trying to take two matrices A,B both with R rows and N columns. I want to form the outer product of each row with the row of the other, i.e.  A_j outer B_j for j=1,...,R. I come from a mathematics background and your coding has me stumped. Can you describe how einsum is used to accomplish this task?

Comment: @jamesmartini please create a new question